# Why is Boruto's Dojutsu different?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Usually most Dojutsu Kekkkai Genkai come in pairs. What I mean by this is, the Sharingan, Rinnengan, Byakugan and even Tensengan usually always come in pairs (for both eyes) but then Boruto only awakened his Jogan in just one eye.

Is there a solid explanation for this? or is it synonymous to how Sasuke only awakened his Rinnegan in only one eye?

Answer (score 1):

Sasuke did not awaken his Rinnegan himself.It was given to him by Hagoromo,he had no such "choice" of awakening only one Rinnegan.It was Hagoromo's decision to give him only one Rinnegan to avoid it's misuse which Madara had done.

Coming to Boruto's Jougan,it's just a very rare case of Byakugan that was triggered probably because of Naruto's enormous chakra.He awakened it only in one eye,not two,the explanation for which is not very clear.